# Is it possible to convert a 1-element list of float values to an array of float values?

Tags: python

Each `TQV_xxxx` is a 296x296 array of float values that I added together to get what I thought would be a similar 296x296 arrays of float values containing their sum. Instead of it being a float type, it appears as a list, containing a float array. I need to make further calculations on the array but it will not let me do it with a list. Is there any way to convert a list of floats to simply a float array?

```
TQV_sum_least= [[TQV_1986], [TQV_2002], [TQV_1984], [TQV_1990], [TQV_2010], [TQV_1989],
                [TQV_1989], [TQV_1996], [TQV_1997], [TQV_2011]]
TQV_sum_least=[sum(x) for x in zip(*TQV_sum_least)]
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image: my list/array]

Why is `TQV_sum_least` a list and not a float array like the others? And why does it appear as a float when I click on the single-element list?

Is there something I can change in the above code to produce a float array?

Comment: apologies if my terminology is off at all

Comment: `np.array(TQV_sum_least)`?

Comment: What `sum` function are you using? The built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) doesn't handle arrays (although it's unclear what the type of the arrays are in your question).

Comment: Please edit this to include a [mcve] that people here can copy and run.